# How to pass the value of <@spring.formSingleSelect..> to javascript?

Tags: freemarker

How to pass the formSingleSelect  vale to js function

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunction(var id){
    alert("hi"+id);
}

<@spring.formSingleSelect  path="LoginIDForm.ID"  options=userIDs    attributes='onChange="myfunction();"'/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this will work:

```
<@spring.bind path="LoginIDForm.ID" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myfunction(var id){
        alert("hi" + id);
    }
</script>

<@spring.formSingleSelect path="LoginIDForm.ID" options=userIDs 
    attributes='onChange="myfunction(\'${spring.status.expression}\');"'/>
```

Basically `<@spring.formSingleSelect  path="LoginIDForm.ID" />` is the shorthand of doing:

```
<@spring.bind path="LoginIDForm.ID" />
<select name="${spring.status.expression}">

</select>
```

`${spring.status.expression}` holds the value you need.

Comment: Thanks attributes='onChange="myfunction(this);" ' work for me